# Flex 4 app behind proxy server w/auth fails to call webservice when launched from IE (firefox ok)

Tags: apache-flex, internet-explorer, proxy, web-services, flex4

I have Flex 4 app which is deployed in internet.

Just as an intro, when i'm behind our corporate proxy server, IE and firefox asks for username and password when accessing external websites.

**WHEN BEHIND PROXY**

In IE (i tested only in 8) Flex app starts fine, but it fails to invoke webservice - CallResponded result or fault event doesn't fire.

In Firefox absolutely the same application works perfectly anywhere.

**WHEN NOT BEHIND PROXY**

When i'm not behind proxy, everything works ok in both browsers.

**BTW**

Of course, proxy server address is not known at compile time.
Webservice is simple one, no https or credentials needed. Located on the same webserver.

**QUESTION IS...**

How to modify app or deployment parameters (now they are Flex 4' defaults) so this app can work anywhere, even behind proxy server and opened from IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual problem was with crossdomain.xml - actually it was absent.

And it turned out that from Firefox i was accessing site with 'www' prefix, so Flash thought it was another domain and refused to load data from it.

Answer (score 0):

In the top menu try to manage on:
Window --> Preferences --> General --> Web Browser

Comment: Thanks, but looks like it's only relevant to debug session's browser.

Comment: I've just made a search on google and it seems that at the moment IE 8 is not supported by Flex 4 Beta:
http://shanazvakil.wordpress.com/2009/06/05/basic-troubleshooting-when-flex-automation-does-not-work/

Comment: They do now, i think, as long as browser supports Adobe Flash player 10.